# Conflicting type errors in function - C

Tags: c

I'm having issues getting a function built for finding a numbers most significant bit operating in my program. Here's the code I was using for testing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void msbFinder(unsigned int);

int main()
{
    unsigned int x;
    printf("Input hexadecimal: ");
    scanf("%x", x);
    unsigned int y;
    y = msbFinder(x);
    printf("Most significant bit: %x", y);
}

unsigned int msbFinder(unsigned int x) //--Finds most significant bit in unsigned integer
{
    unsigned int a; //--Declare int that will be manipulated
    a = x; //--Initialise equal to passed value
    a = a|a>>1;
    a = a|a>>2;
    a = a|a>>4;//--var is manipulated using shifts and &'s so every value at and beneath the MSB is set to 1
    a = a|a>>8;//--This function assumes we are using a 32 bit number for this manipulation
    a = a|a>>16;
    a = a & ((~a >> 1)^0x80000000);//--Invert the int, shift it right once, & it with the uninverted/unshifted value
    return (a);//--This leaves us with a mask that only has the MSB of our original passed value set to 1
}
```

I'm using the Qt Creator, and the errors are:

```
void value not ignored as it ought to be
    y = msbFinder(x);
        ^
```

And:

```
conflicting types for 'msbFinder'
unsigned int msbFinder(unsigned int x)
             ^
```

I've taken a look for solutions online, but I can't see the faults that are causing this function call to fail. How do I need to fix up my syntax to get this function to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration at the top of the file says:

```
void msbFinder(unsigned int);
```

The function definition says:

```
unsigned int msbFinder(unsigned int x)
```

Do you see the difference between `void` and `unsigned int`? The declaration needs to match the definition.

Comment: Dammit, I'm a moron. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 2):

In forward declaration function type is `void` -

```
void msbFinder(unsigned int);
```

And while defining function it is defined as -

```
unsigned int msbFinder(unsigned int x)   /*  <-- type given as unsigned int  */
```

You need to change type of function in forward declaration to `unsigned int`.